# Creating multimap of structs

Tags: c++, multimap

I am trying to create an multimap of structs , i have declared a struct

```
struct Student{
   Student(){};
   Student( string n , int a ){
      name = name;
      age  = age;
   }
  string name;
  int age;
}
```

created a multimap

```
multimap< string , Student > classRoom;
```

and created a function that should push it in the multimap

```
void addStudent( string name , int age ){
 Student tmp( name , age );
 classRoom[ name ] = tmp;
}
```

if i use typical `map` this works , but using `multimap` this throws

> error: no match for ‘operator[]’

Why is this happening  and how can i fixt it? Moreover how does the implementation  differ in these two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with structs; you'd have the same problem with an `int` (narrow down your problems!). The problem is that you didn't look up how to use a multimap.

In a map, the `[]` operator gives you the value that corresponds to a key.

In a multimap, the whole point is that each key may correspond to multiple values, so there cannot be a `[]` operator.

**Use the `insert` function instead.**

Consult *[documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)* for the language features that you use instead of guessing then giving up!